# How to check from .net code whether "Trust access to the VBA project object model" is enabled or not for an Excel application?

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-excel

How to check from .net code whether "***Trust access to the VBA project object model***" is enabled or not for an Excel application?

Manually I can check it from Excel application- ***File>Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Macro Settings>Trust access to the VBA project object model***

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot directly access this setting using the Excel object model (i.e. through PIAs).
However, instead, you can check this setting from the registry in the following location (here I assume that you're using Office 2007 - version 12.0):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM
```

this is a DWORD that will be 0 or 1 depending on whether the "Trust access to VBA Object Model" is enabled.

However, this setting can be overriden by another registry key located at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM
```

this is again a DWORD, however, if this value is 0 this means that no matter what the HKCU value is set to, then access to the VBOM will be denied. If the value in HKLM is 1 or missing, then the HKCU key will control the access to the VBOM.

Therefore, all you need to do is to check these two keys via the Registry methods in .NET.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
Function VBATrusted() As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    VBATrusted = (Application.VBE.VBProjects.Count) > 0
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Not VBATrusted() Then
    MsgBox "No Access to VB Project" & vbLf & _
      "Please allow access in Trusted Sources" & vbLf & _
      "File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings > Trust Access..."
    End If
End Sub
```

Source https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/659774-checking-if-trust-access-visual-basic-project-ticked.html

Comment: Nice solution, but instead of
`VBATrusted = (Application.VBE.VBProjects.Count) > 0`
i would suggest using something else like
`VBATrusted = (Application.VBE.CommandBars.Count) > 0`
because the former check can return false results if the current XL app has no macros inside. The latter check just counts default CommandBars which returned 30 for my Excel Version 16.0 (2016).

Answer (score 0):

Search the registry for all instances of "AccessVBOM" and change the Dword settings to a 1.

That should turn it on.

Comment: One-line answers should be posted as comments. In addition, was does your "answer" add compared to the answer by @i_saw_drones?

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that `Application.VBE` will (depending on OFFICE version) either be `*null*` or throw a `COMException` whenever the **VBA Project Object Model** is not trusted.

If one is using *Office.Interop* in an Add-In then `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.VBE` will perform the necessary test.

I have used this proxy for years successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This code checks if the VBA object model is trusted. If it is not, the code opens the Macro Setting dialog so the user doesn't have to navigate to it.

```
'_2023_03_20
Function fTestGetAccessVBE()
    MsgBox fGetAccessVBE(True)
End Function

'_2024_02_15
Function fGetAccessVBE(Optional blnDialog As Boolean = False) As Boolean
Dim blnAccess As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next    '_2024_02_15
    blnAccess = Not IsError(Application.VBE.CommandBars.Count > 0)  'error if access not trusted

    Select Case True
    Case blnAccess = True   'we have access
    Case blnDialog = True   'else if we want to prompt user to enable
        MsgBox "Programmatic access to the VBA project is not trusted." 'prompt
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MacroSecurity")    'open macro setting dialog
        blnAccess = Not IsError(Application.VBE.CommandBars.Count > 0)  'now check again
    End Select

    fGetAccessVBE = blnAccess   'return access state
End Function

'_2021_10_01
Sub fOpenVbaEditor()
    If fGetAccessVBE(True) = False Then Exit Sub    'done if no access
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True   'else open vba
End Sub
```