# Read Excel VBA Macro Security Settings

Tags: excel, vba, security

I have created a macro-enabled Excel workbook that requires users to have "Trust access to the VBA project object model" enabled in the Excel Macro Security settings.

[image: macro security settings]

I forgot I had already done this, and my coworker got stuck on (not responding) when trying to run the macro.

This window can also be brought up with this code:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("MacroSecurity")
```

Can I programmatically determine the value of this checkbox with VBA?  I'd like to be able to check whether a user has this feature enabled before allowing them to run the macro that could potentially hang up their machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300770/how-to-check-from-net-code-whether-trust-access-to-the-vba-project-object-mode   For .NET but same basic principles apply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check from .net code whether "Trust access to the VBA project object model" is enabled or not for an Excel application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300770/how-to-check-from-net-code-whether-trust-access-to-the-vba-project-object-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, y'all

```
Private Function VBATrusted() As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    VBATrusted = (Application.VBE.CommandBars.Count) > 0
End Function
```